# Code in .htaccess not working

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to convert my urls to seo friendly ones.

I want my url

```
http://exmaple.com/category.php?id=1
```

to

```
http://example.com/arts.html
```

This is what I have tried.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 404.php

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ category.php?id=$1 [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ category.php?id=$1 [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

But it's not working. My 404 redirection and striping www is working fine.

Comment: Your rule rewrites `arts.html` -> `category.php?id=arts`

Comment: Remove the `R=301`, so you end up with `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ category.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]`, which allows `arts.html` to act as an alias for the URL `category.php?id=arts`.  If you need arts.html to be mapped to category ID = 1, you might need to use a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html)

Comment: @beerbajay So are you saying that I should write code like this 'RewriteRule ^category.php?id=$1 ([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ [QSA,NC,L]'.

Comment: @duncan I have removed R=301 but it still not redirecting to new url

Comment: You need some kind of mapping between your "seo names" and the category ids.

Comment: @beerbajay I am sorry but I don't know anything about mapping, can you help me out with the topic. I'm reading from the link **duncan** posted but i can't get what i need to do.

Comment: Your rewrite can't magically figure out that `arts` = category 1. You need to somehow handle this.

Comment: @beerbajay so instead of `category.php?id=1` if i use `category.php?name=arts` will it work with the above said code?

Comment: Yes, that would probably work.